# 301 moved permanently with socket.http

Tags: sockets, http, lua

In python (and my browser), I am able to send a request to `https://www.devrant.com/api/devrant/rants?app=3&sort=algo&limit=10&skip=0` and get a response, as expected, but with Lua, I get `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
http = require("socket.http");
print(http.request("https://www.devrant.com/api/devrant/rants?app=3&sort=algo&limit=10&skip=0")
```

which outputs an HTTP error page (moved permanently) and

```
301    table: 0x8f32470    http/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
```

the table's contents are:

```
location    https://www.devrant.com/api/devrant/rants?app=3&sort=algo&limit=10&skip=0
content-type    text/html
server    nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
content-length    194
connection    close
date    Mon, 11 Dec 2017 01:41:35
```

Why does only Lua get this error? If I request to google, I get the google home page HTML. If I request to status.mojang.com, I get the mojang server statuses in a JSON response string, so the socket is functional for certain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you are using `socket.http` to request a page from `https` URL; since `socket.http` doesn't handle `https`, it sends the request to port 80, which gets forwarded to `https` URL, but `socket` library doesn't follow that redirect, as it doesn't "know" what to do with https, so it simply reports 301.

You need to install and use luasec and use `ssl.https` instead of `socket.http`, which will make it work.

Comment: Is there anything I can do with vanilla Lua?

Comment: No; you need luasocket and luasec.